# Prove using properties of divisors and or induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

How would I go about proving the statement that for all positive integers $n$, $$(n+1)\Big|\binom{2n}{n}$$

Induction in this case is possible but I wanted to use a different method. If I compute $$\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$ I would be able to get $$\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!(n)!},$$ where $n$ is non negative. Would I be able to use a theorem with the greatest common divisor? If I were to use induction, how should I do it?

Comment: When you wrote $\binom2n$, did you mean $\binom{2n}n$?

Comment: $1|1, \; 2|2 \; 3|2 FAIL$

Answer (score 2):

As you observed
$$\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{2n+1}{n}$$

Therefore
$$n+1 | (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}$$

Now, show that $n+1$ is relatively prime to $2n+1$.